# opening file with php not working

Tags: php

Why does:

```
$test='tester.txt';
$bigarr=str_getcsv($test,',');
print_r($bigarr);
```

`texter.txt` contains: `one,two,three,four`

Not work please?

EDIT: It outputs just 'tester.txt' and does not put the individual elements into an array like it is supposed to...

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen and what really happens. Include your steps to reproduce the error and any error messages you receive.

Comment: `str_getcsv()` only accepts a string of data, you would need to open the file first with `fopen()` and then read it's contents. Check the function definition: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php and you're probably looking for: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php instead, check the examples.

Comment: does the row in texter.txt have a proper row delimiter?

Comment: Anton is correct here. Also, you might want to double check that you have php version >= 5.3.0...

Comment: I don't understand why I have -2 votes.  I thought the purpose of this website was to help people with programming problems.  If I knew the answer, I wouldn't need to ask?

Comment: You should do some more research effort beforing asking a question, that's the problem here if i've understood it correctly.

Comment: but the answers have +4 votes.  That means people are finding new things too, so I'm not just stupid...

Comment: No one is calling you stupid but you should at least lookup the function definition before asking why it doesn't work. Also try to include more of what you would expect from the function etc.

Comment: @David19801: You're expected to do some basic research in documentation before resorting to asking for free help. This isn't a free-for-all spoonfeeding collective. Also your initial question just said that your code "didn't work", which is completely useless and not indicative of any sort of analysis on your own effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not opened the file. [`str_getcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) retrieves CSV data from a string, not from a file.  Use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead:

```
$test='tester.txt';
$handle = fopen($test, 'r');
$bigarr = fgetcsv($handle);
print_r($bigarr);
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of such a function. That's a better answer than mine. +1!

Comment: This wouldn't work either since fgetscsv needs a file handle, ie: something opened with: `fopen('file', 'r');` or something like that.

Comment: Correct Anton, this is not working for me either...I will try with fopen.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on [the documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), `str_getcsv` takes a string of CSV. You're passing it a file name. You must first read the content of that file, and use that with the function. You can use [file_get_contents](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
$bigarr = str_getcsv(file_get_contents($test), ',');
```